# Sort std::vector by an element inside?

Tags: c++

I currently have a std::vector which holds std::vector of double. I'd want to sort it by the second element of the double vectore. ex:
instead of sorting by MyVec[0] or myvec[1] I wat it to sort myVec[0] and myvec[1] based on myvec[0][1] myvec[1][1]. Basically sort by a contained value, not the objects in it.

so if myvec[0][1] is less than myvec[1][1] then myvec[0] and myvec[1] will swap.
Thanks

Comment: Any reason you couldn't copy the key value out of the array and then sort to prevent race conditions?

Comment: @Michael, what about the above introduces race conditions? Personally, I'd be more concerned about ensuring every element in this vector of vectors has at least 2 elements. I'd be included to use the `at` function instead of the subscript operator, just to catch this.

Comment: Depending upon how the compare is written, part way through the sort, element[1] may be changed due to the sort and then if teh value is uncached, bad things can occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write the comparator:

```
bool my_comparator(const std::vector<double>& lhs, const std::vector<double>& rhs)
{
  assert(lhs.size() >= 2 && rhs.size() >= 2);
  return lhs[1] < rhs[1];
}
...
std::sort(big_vector.begin(), big_vector.end(), my_comparator);
```

It is better to write a functor instead of a function, but the concept is the same.

Comment: This scares me...there's no check to ensure whether lhs & rhs has `size() >= 2`. May I suggest one of the following: `assert(lhs.size() >= 2) && assert(rhs.size() >= 2)` at the entry to the function or, `return lhs.at(1) < rhs.at(1)`. The first would only check under debug compilations, but would add a certain amount of sanity. The second will check under both debug & release builds, but would have a bit of additional overhead.  As it stand, to me, this code is a recipe for spurious segfaults.  Additionally, vectors of vectors tends to reek of a bad design and should be carefully considered.

Comment: @Nathan Sanity checking is a must in real code, but this isn't supposed to be production code :). Anyway, I changed the code according to your suggestion.

Comment: cheers. I'm just afraid of too much copy/paste from answers into real code, so I feel we must be pedantic. You've earned my +1.

Answer (score 1):

This is something like a vector of strings, except instead of a string of characters, we've got a string of numbers. I think you want this:

```
[
  [1, 0, 4],
  [4, 9, 9],
  [0, 1, 9],
  [4, 5. 2]
]
```

... to sort to ...

```
[
  [0, 1, 9],
  [1, 0, 4],
  [4, 5. 2],
  [4, 9, 9]
]
```

...right?

To do that, you'll need to write a comparator class or function that takes two vectors of numbers, and returns "true" if the first is less than the second. Like:

```
bool my_comparator(const std::vector<double> &a, const std::vector<double> &b)
{
    // return true if a < b ... by comparing a[0] with b[0], etc.
}
```

then pass that to sort():

```
sort(?, ?, my_comparator);
```